# How to use 'epistemology' or its derivative, in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage

The word 'epistemology' is what I understand to convey the sentiment I wish to write. I wish to write, in a more academic manner, "The movie allows people who have not had an abortion to experience the psychological turmoil that occurs".

People who don't have the experience of undergoing an abortion don't have the 'knowledge', ie this relates to epistemology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you simply will not be able to use the word "epistemology" in that sentence; those in philosophy like to keep its use, as far as possible, in reference to the discipline itself - that is, the study of the nature of knowledge. (And it seems to me that, in Marius Hancu's quote, Mr. and Mrs. Carmody are indeed using the word in that way - to refer to the study - just as they are using the word "ethics" to refer to the study of morality, and just as I might use the word "metaphysics" in the same place in the sentence to mean that my account of fundamental reality is inadequate to the demands of environmental problems.)

I think the closest you will be able to get, if you are okay with such an esoteric statement, is saying, "The movie allows people who have not had an abortion to have a sympathetic epistemic experience of the psychological turmoil that occurs." Here, when you say "sympathetic epistemic experience," you simply mean to indicate an experience of the mind (not of the body) that granted you a sort of intuitive knowledge of what it would be like to undergo an abortion procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the language of current philosophy allows one to write this equality:

to have the knowledge = to have the [required] epistemology

which you seem to want to use.

Probably not, as this to me is a simplification, for "epistemology" is not knowledge itself, but the methods leading one to it. However, one finds:

> How to Live Well: Ethics in the World Religions - Page 176 Denise
>   Lardner Carmody, ‎John Carmody - 1988
>
> As long as we define reality solely in terms of how things register in
>   human consciousness or what they imply for human beings' welfare, we
>   shall not **have the epistemology** or the ethics that our environmental
>   problems now demand of us.

where the two sides in the relation seem awfully close.